# Need hair particles to only be on the vertex group, but still sticking out all throughout the mesh

Tags: particles, hair, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, emission

I'm trying to make low poly hair and need the hair particles to only stick out of the top of my mesh on the vertex group I made

[image: This is my vertex Group]

[image: But as you can see it sticks out all throughout the mesh despite assigning the vertex group how do I fix this?]

Comment: Did you assign the vertices to the group?  It doesn't automatically assign the selection when you create a group.

Comment: Yes I did @AllenSimpson I'm 99% sure I did at least that's just where I select which faces and then hit "assign" on the vertex groups tab correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are emitting particles from faces:

[image]

When you limit it with a vertex group the behavior is to emit particles from every face associated with those vertices.  This means a selection like this:

[image]

Emits from every face but the bottom ones.

[image]

You can perhaps work around this with reduced selection or creative additional geometry.